# How do I print out the attributes stored in an array instead of the objects?

Tags: python, arrays, object, printing, instance

How do I print out the attribute of chaptername stored in an array instead of it's object?

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self._chapters = []

    def addchapter(self, chapter):
        self._chapters.append(chapter)

    def getchapters(self):
        #How do I print out ["First", "Second", "Third"] instead?
        print(self._chapters) #<- prints out [<__main__.Chapter object at 0x10b849c40>, <__main__.Chapter object at 0x10b8901f0>, <__main__.Chapter object at 0x10b890310>]


class Chapter:
    def __init__(self, chaptername):
        self._chaptername = chaptername

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._chaptername}"


b = Book()
b.addchapter( Chapter("First") )
b.addchapter( Chapter("Second") )
b.addchapter( Chapter("Third") )
b.getchapters()
```

I'm new to python so I'm not sure what is the way to achieve this and I would really appreciate if someone could help me out! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to override `__repr__` instead of `__str__`.

Comment: Oh my god! You're a life saviour! Thank you so much

Comment: Could I also access it like an array like this as it's not an array? print(self.__chapters[1])

Comment: @Shee yep try it out

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you!